# algorithm implementation error (DFS)

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

I was trying to implementing dfs to print paths from starting node . I followed algorithm from **Coremen** 's book . Here is my code :
[DFS](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17539061/)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

int vertex,edge,source,time,adjacency_matrix[100][100],parent[100],Distance[100],Finishing_time[100];
string color[100];
stack<int> result;
void inputGraph();
void initialize();
void doDFS();
void doDFSvisit(int);
void printPath();
//void printAll();
//void printAdjacencyMatrix();
//void printColor();
//void printDistance();
//void printParent();

int main(void)
{
    inputGraph();
    //initialize();
    doDFS();
    printPath();
    //printAll();
    return 0;
}
void inputGraph()
{
    cout<<"Total vertex : ";
    cin>>vertex;
    cout<<"Total edge   : ";
    cin>>edge;
    int i,j;
    for(i=1; i<=edge; i++)
    {
        int start,finish;
        cout<<"Enter start and end node for edge "<<i<<" : ";
        cin>>start;
        cin>>finish;
        adjacency_matrix[start][finish]=1;
    }
    cout<<"The adjacency matrix is : "<<endl;
    for(i=1; i<=vertex; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=vertex; j++)
        {
            cout<<adjacency_matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void initialize()
{
    cout<<"Enter source node : ";
    cin>>source;
}
void doDFS()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=vertex;i++)
    {
        color[i]="white";
        parent[i]=0;
    }
    time=0;
    for(i=1;i<=vertex;i++)
    {
        if(color[i]=="white")
        {
            doDFSvisit(i);
        }
    }
}
void doDFSvisit(int node)
{
    int i;
    time=time+1;
    Distance[node]=time;
    color[node]="grey";
    for(i=1;i<=vertex;i++)
    {
        if(adjacency_matrix[node][i]==1)
        {
            if(color[i]=="white")
            {
                parent[i]=node;
                doDFSvisit(i);
           }
        }
    }
    color[node]="black";
    //extra line for result
    result.push(node);
    //
    time=time+1;
    Finishing_time[node]=time;
}
void printPath()
{
    cout<<"Path :"<<endl;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=result.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<result.top()<<" -> ";
        result.pop();
    }
    cout<<" End"<<endl;
}
```

My problem :

for input :

> 6
>
> 6
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 4
>
> 2 3
>
> 3 4
>
> 5 3
>
> 5 6

my output should be :

> 5 6 1 2 3 4 end

but my output is :

> 5 6 1 2 end

it seems printing values from stacks creates problem . please correct me where i did mistake , Thanks in advance .

[ P.S. : Pic of the directed graph that I used for input , https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeZg3.jpg ]

Comment: Thanks to your 'images', I am afraid you won't get help, anytime soon. :(

Comment: In order to make sure the input is not the problem, replace it with hard-coded values. Also, please clean up your code and remove everything that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is mistake in the print_path function.
Your for-loop termination condition checks result(stack)'s size which decrements each loop-iteration by pop calling.

Your print_path function should look like something like this:

```
void printPath(){
    cout<<"Path :"<<endl;
    int i;
    while(!result.empty()){
        cout << result.top() << " -> ";
        result.pop();
    }
    cout<<" End"<<endl;
}
```

Additionally consider this DFS implementation:

```
list<size_t> l[N];
bool used[N];
void DFS(size_t s){
    if (used[s])
        return;
    used[s] = true;
    for(auto i = l[s].begin(); i != l[s].end(); i++)
        if(!used[*i]){
            DFS(*i);
        }
}
```

used is global bool array indicating i'th vertex is visited or not. We have no need to color vertexes. We have to know is it already visited or not.

l is adjacency list (see http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/ )

We run DFS on some vertex.
If it's visited we do nothing.
Else we mark this vertex as visited. And then go deeper running DFS on each vertex adjacent current vertex.

For more information about DFS see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would implement DFS in C++. First some observations:

- I'll use adjacency lists (`std::vector`s) rather than an adjacency matrix.
- `Node`s aren't owned by their neighbors. They're assumed to be owned by a parent `Graph` object.

So, without further ado:

```
struct Node {
    std::vector<Node *> neighbors;
    // Other fields may go here.
}

void process(Node * node)
{
    // Actual logic for processing a single node.
}

// Of course, in idiomatic C++, this would be a template
// parameterized by a function object, rather than contain
// a hard-coded call to a fixed `process` function.
void depth_first(Node * start)
{
    std::stack        <Node *> pending = { start };
    std::unordered_set<Node *> visited;

    while (!pending.empty()) {
        Node * current = pending.pop();
        process(current);
        for (Node * neighbor : current->neighbors)
            if (visited.find(neighbor) == visited.end()) {
                pending.push  (neighbor);
                visited.insert(neighbor);
            }
    }
}
```

A nice thing about this implementation is that, in order to get BFS, you only need to replace `std::stack` with `std::queue`, and leave the rest of the code exactly as is.